# How to transform Csv to Nested Json Using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am having issues with converting csc to nested json.
I read similar topics here, but unfortunately was not able to move later :(  Thanks much for your advices.
The simplified csv looks like:

[image: csv input]

And the desired json should be as follows:

```
{"data_type": 1,"person": {"id":1,"name": "Anne","surname": "Frank"},
{"data_type": 2,"address": {"id":1,"street": "de Bruijn","city": "Amsterdam"}
{"data_type": 1,"person": {"id":2,"name": "Terry","surname": "Gilliam"},
{"data_type": 2,"address": {"id":2,"street": "Westminster","city": "London"}
```

I am using pandas and I am struggling with following issues:

- don't know how to avoid inserting blank cells in structure (e.g.: no inserting of "Addres"" for data_type of 1
- sorting should be according to person id
- I can't achieve the desired structure - trying to use groupby, but still receiving something else ...

Comment: Is it really necessary to not insert the NULL values? What functions/modules are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each row and convert them according to your format:

```
cols = ['id', 'name', 'surname', 'street', 'city']

make_dict = lambda row: {
    'data_type': row['data_type'],
    row['data_name']: row[cols].dropna().to_dict()
}
df.apply(make_dict, axis=1).to_list()
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "data_type": 1,
    "person": {"id": 1, "name": "Anne", "surname": "Frank"}
  },
  {
    "data_type": 2,
    "address": {"id": 1, "street": "de Brujin", "city": "Amsterdam"}
  },
  {
    "data_type": 1,
    "person": {"id": 2, "name": "Terry", "surname": "Gilliam"}
  },
  {
    "data_type": 2,
    "address": {"id": 2, "street": "Westminster", "city": "London"}
  }
]
```

Comment: Can I ask you why it is not possible to define three-levels structure in make_dict = lambda row: { ...

Comment: I mean: data_type = level 1, person = level 2, [cols] = level 3    ..... don't yoy know how to write the structure into lambda row ... ? Thanks much